# Ошибка при отправке фото aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
    photo=('test.png','rb')
    if data['age'].isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
        await Form.F.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('Введи целое положительное число')
```

Error

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-53' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Image_process_failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\main.py", line 77, in process_age
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 565, in send_photo
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Image_process_failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Картинка должна быть открыта перед тем, как ее отправлять, из-за этого ошибка. Судя по тому, что вы указали `('test.png','rb')`, вы просто забыли дописать `open`. Исправьте код так:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
    photo=open('test.png','rb') # Вот тут ее нужно открыть, а не просто путь указать
    if data['age'].isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
        await Form.F.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('Введи целое положительное число')
```